# All solutions of 2D square well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

I'm stuck on a 2D square potential well:$$ \frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2} +  \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2})\Psi(x, y)  +  U(x, y)\Psi(x, y) = E\Psi(x, y)$$
$$U(x, y)  =\begin{cases}0 & 0 < x < a, 0 < y < a\\ \infty  & otherwise\end{cases} $$

I want to find all independent solutions of that problem. All that i have is a  pretty nice solution based on the assumption that wave function can be factored as $\Psi(x, y) = \Psi_x(x)\Psi_y(y)$. But i haven't found anywhere the proof that that there are no other independent solutions of that problem. I'll be glad if somebody help me with the proof or another independent solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You got a Fourier series in 2 variable. And since Fourier series are complete any function in 2 variable can be written as a Fourier series in 2 variable
To see this in action see Ex 3.3 in Griffiths electrodynamics.
Also take a look at the image as well. There might be a copyright issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFIxz.jpg)

Comment: This isn't even true in one variable. Kolmogorov constructed a continuous function in one variable whose Fourier series _diverges_ everywhere (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608394/explicit-example-of-a-divergent-fourier-series).

Comment: A wavefunction can't be such kind of pathological function.

Comment: Why not? The above function is continuous. Wavefunctions need not be differentiable; for example, see the eigenfunction of the Dirac-delta potential.

Comment: Is it square integrable? More technical does it even lie in Hilbert space?

Comment: Ah, I see. It's in $L^1$, but I don't know if it's in $L^2$. From the Math SE post I linked to, apparently the function itself is integrable, but maybe it's not square-integrable.

Comment: What about this result, from Price? "For every complete orthonormal system Φ there is an L2 function g whose Φ-Fourier series can be rearranged to diverge almost everywhere."
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376110/generalized-fourier-series-in-l2-that-do-not-converge-pointwise-a-e

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but are you fiddling with the series when you say rearranging it to diverge. Take for an example the alternating harmonic series if you fiddle with it you can get whatever you want from it. Such kind of rearrangement is not allowed. [M.L. Boas Ch-1]

Comment: What if the function corresponding to the rearranged series is also in $L^2$?